# Newrelic not showing data on django

Tags: python, django, newrelic

I have Installed New Relic using These Steps -

1. pip install newrelic ( To install newrelic on my local machine )
2. newrelic-admin generate-config MY_LICENSE_KEY newrelic.ini ( I have created file newrelic.ini in the same folder, where my projects manage.py is located )
3. NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini newric-admin run-program python manage.py runserver ( Command to start server on my local machine)

After that when I tries to connect to my application, the loader keeps running, but nothing happens. It shows the Message - 'Waiting For Data'.
Is there Anyone to help me....
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you run that command as written?

`NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini newric-admin run-program python manage.py runserver`

There is a spelling error in "newric-admin." Try instead:

`NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py runserver`

Also, have you tried testing your connection to the New Relic servers?

`newrelic-admin validate-config newrelic.ini`

There are other testing methods here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/testing-the-python-agent

If you still aren't making headway, please contact New Relic at [support.newrelic.com](http://support.newrelic.com)

Comment: runserver command is working fine.......but when i am running validate-config command....it is giving me warning -
     WARNING - Data collector is not contactable. This can be because of a network issue or because of the data collector being restarted. In the event that contact cannot be made after a period of time then please report this problem to New Relic support for further investigation. The error raised was ProxyError(ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy. Socket error: [Errno 111] Connection refused.',),).

but when same thing i've tried from my friend's machine.....it works fine..